# How to handle long processing task in Express and REST API

Tags: node.js, express, rest, google-cloud-platform

I have very long running task in the back-end.
Here is the scenario,

From the website when I will click the migrate system, the API below will be called

```
/api/system/systemId/migrate
// this will return
// an migration task id -- "123"
```

This will take up to 1 hour. But we don't want the user to wait for such a long time. When the user leaves the page, then comes back to that page, it will show them the current progress. So, whenever I will visit /system/systemId, I can see the progress by calling:

```
/api/system/systemId/migrate/:taskId 
// here task id
//we need to use the migration taskid 
//from the previous api call.
```

And one thing, the progress should be live progress. Like whatever the progress percentage in backend task, we need to show in the UI.

So how can we achieve all of this? Please help me out.

The framework is Node.js, Express, SSE event, and Google Cloud Platform (GCP).